# ASP.NET Membership profile default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164646.aspx) is rather vague regarding this attribute.

> The custom data string can be set to
>   any string value and is set using the
>   customProviderData attribute of the
>   add configuration element for adding
>   profile properties.

Which is the MSDN-esque way of saying figure it out yourself.

From the description it kind of feels like it's plain text you just pass from web.config to a custom provider. But it's not like that, this string seems to build the type of data a given attribute will hold, and I want to know what's the specific format.

In particular, I have the following attributes (and a few more, but I'll just exemplify with two)

```
    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    [CustomProviderData("NotificationTypes;nvarchar;255")]
    public string NotificationTypes
    {
        get { return base["NotificationTypes"] as string ?? "Email"; }
        set { base["NotificationTypes"] = value; }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    [CustomProviderData("IssuesPageSize;int")]
    public int IssuesPageSize
    {
        get { return base["IssuesPageSize"] as int? ?? 10; }
        set { base["IssuesPageSize"] = value; }
    }
```

Here, the custom data seems to determine the name of the field, the db type, and the db length. I was wondering if this attribute could hold a default.

My questions then, are the following:

Can `base[attrib]` ever be null in a `ProfileBase` implementation?
Should I just check against `0` and `string.Empty` if I want to set default values?

The point being that if `base[attrib]` can't ever be null, I don't need the `int?` cast, and I should just be checking against `0`, in that case, and against `string.Empty` in the previous one.

That is, unless there's a "happier" way to set a default value, pretty much like in web.config where you just type:

```
<add name="NotificationTypes" type="String" defaultValue="Email" customProviderData="NotificationTypes;nvarchar;255" />
```

I guess I'm asking how I can add an attribute that is functionally exactly like the one in the `<add/>` tag above, but programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with adding this:

```
    static SharedMembershipProfile()
    {
        Properties["IssuesPageSize"].DefaultValue = 10;
        Properties["NotificationTypes"].DefaultValue = "Email";
        Properties["PreferredLocale"].DefaultValue = "en-US";
    }
```

Still wondering if there's a better approach, like an attribute, or something more "auto-wired"